# Morse code string - follow-up

Tags: java, regex, morse-code

This is probably one of the many follow-ups coming. What I have edited:

- Added `equals()` and `hashCode()`
- Added `.` and `,` to my Morse code "dictionary"
- Used a `Pattern` for regex checking
- Edited method names

Concerns:

- Any bad practices in the new code?
- Does it "smell"?

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MorseString {

    public static final char CHAR_SEPARATOR = ' ';
    public static final char WORD_SEPARATOR = '/';
    public static final char DOT = '.';
    public static final char DASH = '-';

    private String string;
    private String codeString;

    /*
     * Constructor that takes the Morse Code as a String as a parameter
     */

    public MorseString(String s) {
        if(!isValidMorse(s)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("s is not a valid Morse Code");
        }
        if(!s.isEmpty()) {
            this.string = translate(s);
        } else {
            this.string = s; 
        }
        this.codeString = s;
    }

    /*
     * Checks if it is a valid Morse Code
     */

    private static final Pattern VALID_MORSE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
            "(" + Pattern.quote(Character.toString(DASH)) 
            + "|" + Pattern.quote(Character.toString(DOT))
            + "|" + Pattern.quote(Character.toString(WORD_SEPARATOR)) + 
            "|\\s)*");

    public boolean isValidMorse(CharSequence ch) {
        return VALID_MORSE_PATTERN.matcher(ch).matches();
    }

    /*
     * Traslates from Morse in a String to a String
     * e.g. ".... .." to "hi"
     */

    private String translate(String code) {
        String[] words = code.split(Character.toString(WORD_SEPARATOR));
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(words.length * words[0].length()); // Rough guess of size
        for(String word : words) {
            String[] letters = word.trim().split(Character.toString(CHAR_SEPARATOR));
            for(String letter : letters) {
                result.append(MorseCode.decode(letter));
            }
            result.append(CHAR_SEPARATOR);
        }
        return result.toString().substring(0, result.length() - 1);
    }

    public static MorseString parse(String s) {
        // ...
    }

    /*
     * Returns the code as a String
     * e.g. if the object represents "hi" in Morse, it returns ".... .."
     */

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return codeString;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((codeString == null) ? 0 : codeString.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((string == null) ? 0 : string.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof MorseString))
            return false;
        MorseString other = (MorseString) obj;
        if (codeString == null) {
            if (other.codeString != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!codeString.equals(other.codeString))
            return false;
        if (string == null) {
            if (other.string != null)
                return false;
        }
        return string.equals(other.string);
    }

    /*
     * Returns the result of the translations
     * e.g. if the object represents "hi" in Morse, it returns "hi"
     */

    public String asText() {
        return string;
    }

}

enum MorseCode {

    A(".-"),
    B("-..."),
    C("-.-."),
    D("-.."),
    E("."),
    F("..-."),
    G("--."),
    H("...."),
    I(".."),
    J(".---"),
    K("-.-"),
    L(".-.."),
    M("--"),
    N("-."),
    O("---"),
    P(".--."),
    Q("--.-"),
    R(".-."),
    S("..."),
    T("-"),
    U("..-"),
    V("...-"),
    W(".--"),
    X("-..-"),
    Y("-.--"),
    Z("--.."),

    ZERO('0', "-----"),
    ONE('1', ".----"),
    TWO('2', "..---"),
    THREE('3', "...--"),
    FOUR('4', "....-"),
    FIVE('5', "....."),
    SIX('6', "-...."),
    SEVEN('7', "--..."),
    EIGHT('8', "---.."),
    NINE('9', "----."),

    PERIOD('.', ".-.-.-"),
    COMMA(',', "--..--");

    private char character;
    private String code;

    private MorseCode(char character, String code) {
        this.character = character;
        this.code = code;
    }

    private MorseCode(String code) {
        this.character = this.name().charAt(0);
        this.code = code;
    }

    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm referring to this code with the `\\ ...` replaced from your previous post.

### Where are the tests?

I do not see any tests. Where are the tests? You know, tests come first...

### Morse: Usage of `'/'` to separate words?

That's AFAIK not standard Morse, or is it?

### Morse - but which?

There are different Morse alphabets. Which one do you use? Mentioning the corresponding spec in a comment would be nice.

Do you want to support multiple Morse alphabets in the long run?

### If construction is ambiguous, use a factory method instead.

Ideally code is self-explanatory. Looking at the constructor `MorseString.MorseString(String)` I cannot tell whether this constructs a `MorseString` from a `String` by translating the `String` argument into Morse code using the Morse alphabet, or whether this constructs a `MorseString` from a `String` which already is translated Morse code.

In such cases it is better to have private constructors and static factory methods. You already did it half way, `MorseString.parse()` is such a factory method.

You could consider declaring `private MorseString(String)` and provide another factory method instead.

### Use `final` (partially a matter of taste).

The `final` keyword communicates that a variable is not going to change. I recommend it strongly for fields which do not change, and I recommend it even for all other variables.

Especially, use

```
public class MorseString {
    private final String string;
    private final String codeString;
}
```

This makes it more obvious that `class MorseString` is *immutable*. BTW the fact that `class MorseString` is *immutable* is good!

### Premature optimization in `translate(String)`

Guessing the size of the result for the `StringBuilder` is premature optimization. And in case performance matters, there's a better way. How significant is `words[0].length()` really for the length? I would say that `words[0]` is a bad sample because when it comes to most Indo-German languages like English, French, German etc, there's a big chance that the first word of a sentence is very short like 'A', 'I' or 'You'. Wouldn't it be better to use a constant like, say, `7`?

Or, if this is really important for performance, how about a self-tuning, conservative mechanism? Track the average length in a `double averageWordLength` variable, and use a conservative allocation like `new StringBuilder((int) (words.length * (averageWordLength + 3)))` if you really want to avoid reallocations of the `StringBuilder`'s internal buffer.

But really, only optimize when you know that this is a performance hot spot.

### Bug in `translate(String)`.

I believe that `translate(String)` cannot process `""`. That's not very convenient. I'd actually call it a bug.

(I didn't test it, though - did I already ask where are the tests?)

This bug actually complicates the constructor `MorseString` unnecessarily.

Even if the case `s.length() == 0` would need special treatment - then that's because of `translate()` and therefore responsibility of `translate()`, not the constructor. Checking `s.length()` in the constructor is misplaced responsibility.

### Use meaningful names.

The parameter `s` in constructor `MorseString` is assigned to field `codeString`. Therefore it makes sense to name it `codeString` as well, not just `s`. `String s` is totally meaningless, whereas `String codeString` carries a lot of information.

How about calling the things consistently `plainText` and `morseText`? Just suggesting, and I think that would be consistent with how such stuff is usually called in the context of *coding*.

### Provide more information in exceptions.

In the constructor, when you detect that `s` is not a valid Morse string, you do

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("s is not a valid Morse Code");
```

That leaves the programmer clueless what exactly was invalid.

There are two steps about how to improve that.
First of all, include `s` in the exception message, like this:

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("\"" + s + "\"" is not a valid Morse code");
```

The second step is a bit bigger, you could change `isValidMorse(String)` from using a regular expression into using a proprietary parser which can give more information.

### Over-complicated constructor `MorseString`

Shouldn't the constructor simply look like this:

```
public MorseString(String codeString) {
    if (!isValidMorse(codeString))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("\"" + codeString + "\"" is not a valid Morse code");
    string = translate(codeString);
    this.codeString = codeString;
}
```

The fact that in a special case `s` is assigned to both, `string` and `codeString` is confusing. It would've been better to use `""` instead. But even better of course if `translate(String)` would simply accept a `String s` with `s.length() == 0`.

### Avoid overly long methods

`translate(String)` and `parse(String)` are a bit lengthy. Consider simplifying and splitting them.

For example, `parse(String)` contains a special case `if (s.isEmpty()) return new MorseString("");`. Ideally algorithms are written in a way that such special cases are *implicit* (and if they are developed with TDD/TPP, they usually end up this way automatically).

Look at this `sum(int... ops)` method:

```
public static int sum(final int... operands) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (final int operand : operands)
        sum += operand;
    return sum;
}
```

No special case for `operands.length == 0`.

Handling the special cases specially makes algorithmic functions less robust (if we're not speaking of recursive algorithms): You remove a potential test case from testing the core algorithm.

### Redundant `null` check in `equals()`

In `equals()`, the check `if (obj == null)` is redundant. It is defined, guaranteed and (hopefully) well-known that `x instanceof Y` with `x == null` always evaluates `false`.

**EDIT:** The `equals()` could be as simple as this, given that `codeString` and `string` are never `null`:

```
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    return obj instanceof MorseString ? equals((MorseString) obj) : false;
}

public boolean equals(final MorseString obj) {
    return codeString.equals(obj.codeString) && string.equals(obj.string);
}
```

Or if you want to go without a second overloaded `equals()`, like this:

```
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof MorseString))
        return false;
    final MorseString o = (MorseString) obj;
    return codeString.equals(o.codeString) && string.equals(o.string);
}
```

My personal preference is on the variant with the two `equals()` because the individual methods are shorter and pure single-statement expression functions.

Just compare this with your `isValidMorse(CharSequence)` method. This is how functions ideally look like. Your `isValidMorse(CharSequence)` method is really nice.

### Inconsistent `null` check in `equals()` and `hashCode()`

The other null check `if (codeString == null)` actually is inconsistent. The constructor is (currently) written in a way that `codeString` can never be `null`. The constructor takes `String s`, invokes `s.isEmpty()` without `null`-check, which means if this succeeds, `s` is guaranteed to not be `null`, then assignes `codeString = s`.

### Consider using `Objects.hashCode()` and `Objects.hash()` for `hashCode()`.

The expression `(obj == null ? 0 : obj.hashCode())` can be replaced by `Objects.hashCode(obj)`.

However, your `hashCode()` could be as simple as this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(codeString, string);
}
```

### `enum`s are for programmers. Plus, put abstraction in code, details in data.

I wouldn't use an `enum` for the job of translating between plain text and morse text.

Also, `decode` and `encode` are unnecessarily slow. They are `O(n)` with `n` being the size of the Morse alphabet.

A `Map<Character, String>` / `Map<String, Character>` would be `O(log(n))`, and it would be more maintainable. As soon as someone sees `Map` they think "Oh, lookup. Clear." Whereas the `for`-loop has to be read and understood in order to understand that it's a lookup.

If performance matters, you can actually have `O(C)` by using an array with the character as index and special values like `null` or `-1` to denote invalids / gaps in the array.

This works in both directions. A String which represents a single character from the Morse alphabet and therefore contains only `.` and `-` can actually be represented as a binary digit by converting '.' into `0` and '-' into `1`. You need a known start bit in order to distinguish whether the code starts with `0` or `1`. That way you can convert the String into a small int number and use that for looking up the character.

**EDIT:**

### Violation of *SRP - Single Responsibility Principle* regarding plausibility check. Consequence: Inconsistent `MorseString.parse(String)` vs `enum MorseCode`.

While your `enum MorseCode` allows for latin characters, digits, *comma and period*, `MorseString.parse(String)` will still reject such strings because of the guard `if (!s.matches("[\\s\\dA-Za-z]*"))`.

The root cause is the violation of the *SRP - Single Responsibility Principle*. Both classes / methods, `MorseString.parse(String)` and `MorseCode.encode(char)`, are responsible for the plausibility check. The responsibility of the plausibility check has been duplicated, it's not in a single place, and now it has become inconsistent.

The guard actually is entirely redundant. `MorseString.parse(String)` could purely take the responsibility of dealing with multiple characters, i.e. taking care of the `loop`.

### Avoid `break` and `continue` if possible.

`break` and `continue` are `goto` in disguise, i.e. a violation of *structured programming*. Okay, sometimes we need them. But in the case of `MorseString.parse(String)`, the `continue` can easily be avoided by using an `else`.

### Possible violation of the *SRP - Single Responsibility Principle* between `MorseString.parse(String)` and `MorseCode.encode(char)` regarding conversion.

`MorseCode` seems to be responsible for converting all characters *except* some, like `' '` (`SP`).

Consider how much simpler `MorseString.parse(String)` would be if `MorseCode` would also take care of `' '`.

Actually, `MorseString.parse(String)` should be as simple as this:

```
public static MorseString parse(final String plainText) {
    final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (final char c : plainText.toCharArray())
        result.append(MorseCode.encodeForText(c)).append(CHAR_SEPARATOR);
    return new MorseString(result.toString().trim());
}
```

I refer to a not yet existent method `encodeForText` which would return Strings which would be one pause length short to not have overly long pause lengths for those Morse alphabet code words which contain pauses at their ends.

Comment: I use `/` only to _show_ the separation. It is not there for any other purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Quick gotchas:

1. Change the block comments to Javadoc. See [a concise reference](https://students.cs.byu.edu/~cs240ta/fall2012/tutorials/javadoctutorial.html) or the [official documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html).
2. make the `MorseCode` a nested static class of the `MorseString` class, or make it another standalone public class, so that other interested class can access it. Also I would suggest to rename it to `MorseCodeEnum` or like kind so the name won't make people think this is the class that will do Morse code conversions.

Comment: It might be benficial to link to more official resources than some university's student portal. Additionally I find your naming advice somewhat nonsensical given that a proper IDE shows you what kind of type you get from a name, which makes the enum superfluous

Comment: For sure I considered the official document, e.g. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html but I found it's too long and tedious so I searched other resources and found the link very concise and readable.

Comment: About the naming, it just make sense to call it an enumeration, since it's a enumeration of all Morse codes, not because it is an enum type.

Comment: That's a tautology... you're saying that it should be named Enum because it's an enumeration and not because it is an enumeration, because exactly that is what an enum type is....

Comment: Okay, if you prefer.. I just think it doesn't hurt to be clear on the naming.

Comment: In general, we prefer a mix of code suggestions and explanation.  This answer would be much better with an example of how it looks to convert a block comment to Javadoc.  Particularly since a student home page is particularly susceptible to link rot.

Answer (score 3):

Your regex could use a full overhaul... currently you're or-ing characters together into a capture group for any single character.

That's somewhat nonsensical, given you could use a proper character-class instead, which might even speed the regex up.

Use the following as your regex:

```
private static final Pattern VALID_MORSE_PATTERN =
   Pattern.compile("[" + Pattern.quote(".-/") + "\\s]*");
```